# Good resource for building restful API

Tags: php, rest, restful-authentication, slim, silex

I am looking for a good resource which will show me the right way for building a restful API.
Interesting topics: Authentication in particular and security in general, performance, scalability, best practices and other useful things.

I am going to build it in PHP (Slim or Silex) and before I begin I would like to think about the whole design so I can go the right way from the beginning.

There are a lot of info and posts all around the web but all of them adopt different practices and approaches.

Is there something which seems like a "standard" in the restful world?

Comment: Sturgeons book is excellent.

https://leanpub.com/build-apis-you-wont-hate

Answer (score 6):

> Is there something which seems like a "standard" in the restful world?

Not beyond the level of using HTTP. There's a bunch of media types for encoding of API data (see hypermedia below), a lot of different best practices and a good amount of RFC's that covers various aspects of working with HTTP (like for instance authorization using OAuth2).

Here's a compilation of resources worth reading ... I think you will get the most out of reading through one or two of the books.

Authorative resources

- Fieldings original thesis on REST: [http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm](http://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm)

Books

- RESTful Web APIs: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028468.do
- RESTful Web Services Cookbook: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596801694.do
- REST in Practice : http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596805838.do
- RESTful Web Services:  [http://amzn.com/0596529260](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529260)
- Web API Design: https://pages.apigee.com/web-api-design-website-h-ebook-registration.html
- InfoQ E-magazine on REST: http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/emag-rest

Authentication

- Basic considerations: http://soabits.blogspot.dk/2014/02/api-authentication-considerations-and.html
- OAuth2 spec: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749

Error handling

- Best practices: http://soabits.blogspot.dk/2013/05/error-handling-considerations-and-best.html
- "vnd.error" a media type for error details: https://github.com/blongden/vnd.error
- Problem details for HTTP APIs: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-appsawg-http-problem-00

Hypermedia

- Fielding's fameous rant: http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven
- Selling the benefits of hypermedia: http://soabits.blogspot.dk/2013/12/selling-benefits-of-hypermedia.html
- HAL media type: HAL: http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html
- Sirene media type: Sirene: https://github.com/kevinswiber/siren
- Collection+JSON: http://amundsen.com/media-types/collection/format/
- JSON API: http://jsonapi.org/
- Hydra: http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/
- RFC 5988 Web Linking https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988

URL structures

- Basic considerations: http://soabits.blogspot.dk/2013/10/url-structures-and-hyper-media-for-web.html

Partial updates

- Considerations about partial updates: http://soabits.blogspot.dk/2013/01/http-put-patch-or-post-partial-updates.html
- JSON-Patch: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902

Comment: Fielding's original thesis on REST is a rather counterproductive resource to recommend to anyone building a "RESTful API", at least without major caveats. Despite how the term has been appropriated, Fielding's dissertation was not about APIs, and is of little relevance to what we call "REST APIs" today. In fact, Fielding outright claims that ["there is no such thing as a REST API"](https://twitter.com/fielding/status/1108177659375214592)! As a profession, we web devs just nicked Fielding's term and given it a new meaning almost totally unrelated to anything he wrote.

Answer (score 3):

**Some consideration about PHP for building rest APIs**

PHP is a widely used technology since many years.

But during this long period it has shown some relevant problems: it became a monstrous technology and its usage has shown some security vulnerability like SQL injection, lack of a centralized packaging registry, inconsistent API and subpar performance. 
For building REST apis there are more modern technologies, like Ruby on Rails and Django, or Node.js, which is easily approachable.

**Using PHP for building Rest APIS**

You can of course build your apis in php also if better technologies have born in last years. Many companies still uses it in production environments. 
You can choose two different approach to build your infrastructure:

1. building everything from scratch interfacing directly with PHP APIs.
2. staying on an upper level and interface with third party, open
   source libraries to perform some tedious processes like routing,
   authentication and so on.

The second approach lets you save time and focus more on your business logic, by delegating some common operations to trusted third party written code.

For example you can check these libraries that are commonly used in PHP applications to get the job done faster:

1. https://github.com/chriso/klein.php helps you performing the routing
2. https://github.com/PHPAuth/PHPAuth help you with authentication process (check also https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt for stateless authentication).
3. https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver (mongodb) or https://github.com/cagartner/sql-anywhere-client (SQL) You will need to interface with a database and this links are examples of some clients libraries that helps you with the job

**Using something like node.js**

Node.js is a modern technologies built to allow people do what you are going to do. It's fast, scalable (php is less), easy to use and has a very frenetic community that write code and share open source.

For example, using http://expressjs.com/ you can manage the whole routing of your application in minutes. You write your application in javascript so you will have to worry about physiological javascript's problems (closures, async calls etc.), but after have solved this quite tricky part, with node.js you will build a more efficient rest APIs, and your server will need less CPU and power to accepting and answering requests.

Comment: The advise about PHP in this answer is many years out of date and in some cases just plain wrong.  SQL injection for example can happen in any language.  PHP has just as good tools to prevent it than any other language.  PHP has a great package management registry called Composer.  And, performance has gone through the roof with the release of PHP 5.6.  There are many fantastic frameworks available for anything you need to do.  Before PHP 5.4 and Composer, I might have agreed with this bleak outlook on PHP, but these days it is just as good a choice as any other.

Answer (score 2):

For best practices there is a good guideline repository on GitHub. You can go to the following page for more information:

[http-api-design](https://github.com/interagent/http-api-design)

You can also look at Apiary to design APIs:

[Apiary](http://apiary.io/how-it-works)

For authentication actually the best thing to do is to rely on a framework instead of reimplementing from scratch. For learning purposes however thats a different case but for putting it out to production the best bet is to use what the framework provides. Most frameworks have a good implementation which probably has been iterated over time by the community to be quite robust. Certain frameworks like laravel also provides solution for csrf (cross site request forgery) attacks.

Another useful thing that you can look into is JWT (JSON Web Token). Here is useful link which summarises why it is so awesome:

[Stateless tokens with JWT](http://jonatan.nilsson.is/stateless-tokens-with-jwt/)

I don't know how to look into scalability from an API perspective. To me it seems more like an infrastructural issue. However with authentication (session or token based) scalability could become an issue as for example if you have different number of instances serving your users you need to maintain either sticky session or session stored in a quick access key-value store or database.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at [my opinionated presentation](http://vanthome.github.io/rest-api-essay-presentation/rest_apis.html) about REST APIs based on JSON-LD, SemWeb, Hydra Core.